# Laravel+Nuxt CORS getting blocked in production environment

Tags: laravel, axios, cors, nuxt.js

Recently I've moved my Laravel+Nuxt project from local to remote server. Laravel is running on "http://laravelexample.com" domain and Nuxt is running on another domain "http://nuxtexample.com". I've had no CORS errors while running on localhost, all requests/pages work as expected, but when trying it out in server environment only about half of the API requests work, others keep throwing:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://laravelexample.com/api/XXXXX/' from origin 'http://nuxtexample.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.**

Laravel .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
php_value  upload_max_filesize  10M

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
   
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Nuxt .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  mode: 'universal',
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '[EB] - %s',
    title: 'X',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      }
    ],
    script: [
      {
        src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
        type: "text/javascript"
      },
      {
        src:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js",
        type: "text/javascript"
      },
      {
        src:
          "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        type: "text/javascript"
      }
    ],
  },

  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  router: {
    middleware: ["clearValidationErrors"]
  },

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    './plugins/mixins/user.js',
    './plugins/axios.js',
    './plugins/mixins/validation.js',
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  moment: {
    defaultTimezone: 'America/Chicago'
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
  ],

  axios: {
   // Do away with the baseUrl when using proxy
    baseUrl: 'http://laravelexample.com/api/',
  },



  auth: {
        redirect: {
        login: "/login",
        logout: false
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: 'auth/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: "meta.token"
          },
          user: {
            url: '/auth/user-profile',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'data'
          },
          logout: {
            url: 'auth/logout',
            method: 'post'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.teal.lighten1,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

Example of $axios call which causes CORS error:

```
getVendors()
{
  this.$axios.get(`/vendors`).then(res => {
    this.vendors = res.data.data;
  })
```

Example of $axios call which works on the server and does not cause CORS error:

```
    getBreakdowns() {
      let user_company = this.$store.getters['company/getCompany']
      this.$axios.get(`/breakdowns/${user_company}`).then(res => {
        this.breakdowns = res.data.data;
      })
    },
},
```

Google Chrome network tab shows this, when accessing the path with CORS error:
[image]

I've already tried various different proxy setups (but it still only works on localhost, but not on the server). The server is using OpenLiteSpeed if that changes something. But nothing seems to work and I keep seeing the same CORS error, any chance someone has faced something like this and managed to come up with some kind of a fix?

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated, since this has really gotten extremely frustrating.

Comment: Is there any package you have configured for handling CORS on the `laravel` end?

Answer (score -1):

have you implemented CORS Middleware for Laravel?
if not that **might** be the case.

give this [package](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) a try, it sets up a CORS middleware for your project.